# Looping through two arrays to fill a two dimensionnal array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I work on Angular and use Typescript. I have two arrays `array1` and `array2` which I have parsed from an API.

A `console.log` on `array1` looks like this :
[image]

A `console.log` on `array2` looks like this :
[image]

I'd like to create an two dimensionnal array which would merge the two arrays one element by element (id 0 with id 0, id 1 with id 1, id 2 with id 2 and so on). To be clearer the result would be :

```
[["Outils sali", "saunier"], ["outils elem", "outils trad"], ["outils trad", "outils sali"], .... ];
```

Would you have any ideas to realize that trick ?

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you !

Comment: edited tags, this has nothing to do with Angular :)

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both have the same length just use a map operator

```
array1 = []; // imagine filled
array2  = []; // imagine filled

let result  = array1.map((array1Value, index) => [array1Value, array2[index]]);
```

Comment: Thanks @vaira for your answer. I suppose that I should put the map operator in a for loop ?

Comment: map allows you to loop array and return same or edited response of the same length

Comment: Ok I did not know, I was looking for too far...  Thank you very much that works perfectly !

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to give you the desired result, returning an element from arr1 and arr2 for each iteration.

```js
const arr1 = ['outils sali', 'outils elem', 'outils trad', 'matériel', 'produit'];
const arr2 = ['saunier','outils trad', 'outils sali', 'outils trad', 'matériel'];

const result = arr1.map((el, idx) => [el, arr2[idx]]);
console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = ["outils sali", "outils elem", "outils trad", "materiel", "produit"];
const arr2 = ["saunier", "outils trad", "outils sali", "outils trad", "materiel"];

const newArray = []
let subArray = []

for(let i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
    subArray = createArray(arr1[i],arr2[i])
    newArray.push(subArray)
}

function createArray(elem1,elem2) {
    return [elem1,elem2]
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).